# What could be the reason for the error: Error 403: SRVE0190E: File not found: /index.jsp. I am deploying in websphere

Tags: websphere

What could be the reason for the error: Error 403: SRVE0190E: File not found: /index.jsp. 
I am deploying in websphere.
The war is working fine in local (using tomcat). But gives the error when deploying on websphere 6.1.

Please help.

Comment: You may be able to avoid these types of deploy-time surprises by developing on the WebSphere Liberty Profile, which supports drop-in deployment, dynamic updates, and is generally designed to be really enjoyable as a development runtime.

Comment: 403 is permission errors. (I'm assuming you do have an index.jsp in the root of your WAR?)

Comment: @HollyCummins the OP uses WAS 6.1. The Liberty Profile is not available with that version.

Comment: Have you looked in the logs to see the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever seen `SRVE0190E` with 403... only **404**, which is the standard HTTP status code for not-found.

Some initial things to verify:

- Verify your web app is actually deployed.
- Verify your web app is started.  It may deployed but not yet started (red X in the list of applications)
- Verify your web app is deployed to the correct application server, if for example there is a deployment manager instance or a cluster.
- Verify you are accessing the server via the HTTP port that matches the correct application server. For example, `http://[server]:9060/ibm/console` may be your admin console URL but `http://[server]:9060/yourapp/` would likely yield `SRVE0190E` or 404.  In this case you probably want http://[server]:**9080** /yourapp/.  These are the default port values but your server may be configured differently.
- Verify you have mapped the web app to the web server, if there is an IHS (Apache) server in front of WAS in your topology. I doubt this is the case because `SRVE0190E` comes from Application Server.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I followed this Spring framework tutorial: https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/.

Running this sample code on Websphere 8.5, I got the same error message: `Error 403: SRVE0190E: File not found: /index.jsp`.

But there was no error when running at Tomcat server.
(In fact, there still had a issue: this index.jsp page could not render JSP code which encapsulated by `<% ... %>`.)

Finally, I found out the problem was `web.xml`, it set "/index.jsp" as url-pattern in servlet-mapping, but the servlet definition (both XML file and Java code) does not deal with this url-pattern.

If I removed `<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>`, than everything worked fine.

Here is the origin web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   ...
   ... 
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```